# Whatever I type in the terminal I get prompted to install grub?

Tags: command-line, grub2

Ok, whatever I type in the terminal I get the message from the SS after 3sec, and it just goes in a loop, my grub is working fine and I have no idea why this is coming up.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 a few hours ago, clean install, can't use the terminal...

[image]

Update, I did what heemayl said, then tried to run

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties
```

to install Ruby and I get:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So I do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and get the initial SS message all over again.

Here is the content of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bd0b9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2   *      206848   251865087   125829120    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       251865150   870684671   309409761    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda4       870686720   975542188    52427734+  83  Linux
/dev/sda5       251865152   870684671   309409760    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: Press **Ctl+Alt+F1** to open tty1 and then Run **sudo update-grub** and reboot pc. If problem still persists then edit your post to include the output of **sudo fdisk -l**.

Comment: done, see updated post